Poincaré inequality for generic measure?
Let $\Omega$ a smooth bounded domain, and let $\mu$ an absolute measure with respect the Lebesgue measure.
I need to prove the following Poincaré inequality (if it is true!)
$$
\int_\Omega f^2 d\mu \le C \int_\Omega |\nabla f|^2 d\mu.
$$

For which class of functions $f$?

Sorry.  For all $f\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$

Have you tried Radon-Nikodym Theorem? Is this measure positive?

is nonnegative. It vanishes in sets of zero measure.

If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure then $C\lesssim \text{diam}(\Omega)^2$ up to a constant depending only on dimension. Otherwise I think your question is too general to be answered.

I thought this is an interesting quick exercise to work on but as always it turns out to be more involved than it seems to be. I will summarize what I have found so far.
First, by Radon-Nikodym Theorem, we can write $d\mu=gdx$ for some $g\in L^1(\Omega)$. Therefore the question is equivalent to the following: For a non-negative Lebesgue integrable function, does $$\int_\Omega f^2g \leq C\int_\Omega |\nabla f|^2 g \tag{1}$$ hold for all $f\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, for some constant?
Then first obvious observation is, if there are constants such that $0<c_1\leq g\leq c_2$, we have $$\int_\Omega f^2g\leq c_2\int_\Omega f^2\leq C_Pc_2\int_\Omega |\nabla f|^2\leq C_P\frac{c_2}{c_1}\int |\nabla f|^2 g.$$
From this we can see that it becomes problematic if $g$ is not (essentially) bounded from below or above.
Another obvious observation is, if $g$ vanishes at a set $\{x\in\Omega, d(x,\partial\Omega)<\varepsilon\}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ then we can just plug in bump functions that is constant on the support of $g$ to fail (1) easily. Therefore this will fail if support of $g$ is not path-connected to the boundary.
Other than these, there are no obvious conditions that I can find to fail this. I tried to find some counter-examples by looking at $g=x^\alpha$ for $\Omega$ containing $0$, but nothing seems to fail (1).
One thing worth mentioning is, the usual trick we use in measure theory by looking at the sets $$\left\{\frac{1}{n+1}\leq g\leq\frac{1}{n}\right\}\quad\textrm{ or } \quad \left\{n\leq g\leq n+1\right\}$$ doesn't work, since even if these sets are close, we can always plug in constant functions to fail the inequality on these set if they are not path-connected to the boundary.
To sum up, the minimum requirement for (1) to hold is that, support of $\mu$ must be path-connected to the boundary of $\Omega$.

Thank you for your suggestions
